# How do I get UniqueBody from incoming email in EWS?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I have the following code in place, and it works:

```
private void OnEvent(object sender, NotificationEventArgs args)
{
    StreamingSubscription sub = args.Subscription;

    foreach (NotificationEvent notification in args.Events)
    {
        switch (notification.EventType)
        {
            case EventType.NewMail:
                if (notification is ItemEvent)
                {
                    ItemEvent item = (ItemEvent)notification;
                    EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.ItemId);

                    string fAddress = message.From.Address;
                    string subject = message.Subject;
                    string body = message.Body.Text;
                    string tAddress = message.ToRecipients[0].Address;

                    //and so on...
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I try to set "body" equal to UniqueBody like this...

```
string body = message.UniqueBody.Text;
```

That errors out saying, "You must load or assign this property before you can read its value."  I was hoping UniqueBody would work out-of-the-box, meaning I wouldn't have to parse a new email to grab the new details I care about.  I'm assuming there is something easy I'm missing.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you bind the `ItemId` you wish to receive you need to be explicit in which properties you want.

For example,

```
var propertySet = new PropertySet(ItemSchema.UniqueBody);
var email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.ItemId, propertySet);
```

The `PropertySet` class has an overload that includes `params[]` so you're free to include/exclude a number of additional properties. Simply look through the `ItemSchema` enum and select the ones you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up using:

```
PropertySet pSet = new PropertySet(new[]{ ItemSchema.UniqueBody });
pSet.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text;
pSet.BasePropertySet = BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties;
```